# Ploting time series data shows only one time series out of two in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have two time series to plot in single box using matplotlib in python. However, I can see only one line instead of two.

I have a data frame which contain three columns. "A"," B","C". I would like to plot a line chart for "B" and "C" but it only shows "C". Here in my dataset which is pandas data frame and code to plot chart.

```
LI_DF = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0.01,0.03,0.05,0.1],'B':[-315668.07,-944777.38,-1568942.67,-3066239.14],'C':[-317217.21,-949398.31,-1576561.72,-3080043.6]})
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8), dpi=150))
LI_DF.plot(label='LI_DF', color=['orange','green'])
plt.legend()
```

I have checked time series type for all three of them and they are same.

Please see attached two screenshot for data frame and final chart output.

[Database LI_DF image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26an8.jpg)

Final chart output
[image]

Comment: Your code is missing a closing `)`

Comment: Typo here is mainly while writing code to post a question. However, in original code everything is fine.

Comment: Then please do update your question fixing the typos and providing a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: There are commas in those numbers, so they are strings. You need to remove all the commas and then convert to float: `LI_DF = LI_DF.replace(',', '', regex=True).astype(float)`

Comment: @DollarAkshay  I have updated the question with an actual small set of data. Can you please check if you can reproduce the line chart for 'B' and 'C' ?

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8), dpi=150))
```

There was a missing `)`, strange that there wasn't an error raised.

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided has a lot of typos. I think you probably copied it wrong because you should be seeing an error and not a chart.

Fixing those errors :

- Missing closing bracket in `pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C']`
- Missing closing single quote in `color=['orange','green])`

should actually give you 2 line graphs in a single plot.

#### Code

```
small_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5], 'B' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] })
small_df.plot(color=['orange','green'])
plt.show()
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Typo here is mainly while writing code to post a question. However, in original code everything is fine. I am still not able to replicate the same with my original dataset. Is there anything else apart from highlighted above ?

Comment: @AbhayDodiya did you try running my example code that I posted here ?

Comment: I tried your example and it's working fine. In case of my example, it doesn't work. I believe there is an issue with data may be due to float as your example is of type int.

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should also read [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: @Mr.T I have updated the question with an actual small set of data. Can you please check if you can reproduce the line chart for 'B' and 'C' ?

Comment: No, three lines, as the legend will tell you. B and C are too similar, though - they appear to be one line. Set one of the B-values to positive to see the difference. `plt.figure(figsize=(16,8), dpi=150)` is also without effect as you don't pass this figure  (the axis object associated with it, to be precise) to the following pandas plot.

Comment: Here is the output of your sample code with one B data point altered for demonstration purposes: https://imgur.com/lR0f2tn

Comment: @Mr.T I am not concerned about "A" as I am more interested in getting B and C. I know both are identical but still, their values are different it should show two lines with thin margins.

Comment: The differences are below the resolution of your initial image. If you [zoom in](https://imgur.com/RAdbdrE), you see them.